# Can't get video on TV from computer

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I hooked up my PC to my TV and under the resolution settings the TV shows up and is enabled but I do not get any video on the TV.  I hooked my computer up to my 2<sup>nd</sup> TV and the video shows up.  I am doing this all with an HDMI cable and can't get it to work.  This is also not the first time I have hooked this TV to my computer.  It was hooked up the other day and worked just fine.

I am using Windows 7 and have tried shutting everything down and rebooting.  I first turn on the computer and allow it to boot, then I hook the HDMI cable to the computer, then the to the TV like it is a fresh hook up and it still does not work.

Comment: Reboot, change resolution, check inputs, change inputs...

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: Try pulling the plug on your tv, waiting a moment, and plugging it back in.  Also make sure the input is on the correct setting.  Some westinghouse TVs are finicky, but a power reset usually fixes all the strange problems.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions...

- Look up the native screen resolution of the TV, and apply it as the selected *Resolution* in the *Screen Resolution* settings. Try other resolutions as well. I've yet to find a TV that didn't support 640x480.
- Verify if you are using the "Extend these displays" option for the *Multiple displays* combo-box in the *Screen Resolution* settings. If you have it set to this, and have not logged on yet, or use a black background, then this could be tricking you into thinking its not working when it really is and you were just expecting the displays to be duplicated.
- Try connecting the PC to the TV using a different interface such as VGA, [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video), or [component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_video) if you have the option of a different one.
- Try connecting a different computer or other device (e.g. DVD player, Blu-Ray player, Satellite receiver) to the problemativ TV using an HDMI cable.
- Try configuring the multiple display settings so that only the TV is enabled. Be careful with this option though. I'm sure you've already seen it, but after you hit apply, Windows 7 will pop up a dialog asking if you want to keep the changes or reset them. After 15 seconds of no response it automatically revert.
- See if your TV is still under warranty and contact the manufacturer. If it's still under warranty, they will either help you fix the issue, or end up replacing the TV for you.

Answer (score 0):

How many HDMI ports does your TV have? My TVs have atleast 3 each.

If you have multiple HDMI ports, have you tried to use a different port?

Comment: I have 3 hdmi ports and yes I have tried all 3 of them.